# Windows Ping deve retornar somente os valores de resposta dos pacotes

Tags: batch, cmd, script

Estou fazendo um script como comando ping e desejo obter somente a resposta do pacotes enviados e recebidos, até agora só conseguir colocar para aparecer a media do ping utilizando esta variavel :

```
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%i in ('ping -n 4 172.16.7.144^|find "ms"') do set "tempo=%%i"
echo.%tempo%
```

e desejo uma agora que só me mostre os pacotes enviado e recebidos.

Comment: Poderia colocar o texto do prompt e como você quer a saída formatada. Isso facilita para as pessoas vão responder.

Comment: Ewerton, talvez você poderia fazer um programa em C#,  System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping.Send("172.16.7.144");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Executei seu comando no **cmd** sendo que troquei o **find** por **findstr** como abaixo.

```
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %i in ('ping -n 4 172.16.7.144 ^| findstr /i "pacotes"') do set "tempo=%i"
```

O resultado que saiu aqui foi exatamente o que segue.

```
set "tempo=Pacotes: Enviados = 4, Recebidos = 0, Perdidos = 4 (100% de"
```

Depois executei `echo %tempo%` e o resultado foi esse abaixo.

```
Pacotes: Enviados = 4, Recebidos = 0, Perdidos = 4 (100% de
```

A linha morre depois no **de**, mas pelo que você informou era essa informação que queria certo ?

Comment: eu segui esse comando copiando e colando e nao funcionou. grato desde ja , se puder manda novamente pois este nao esta funcionando !

Comment: Eu executei ele direto no **cmd**, e não em um arquivo **.BAT**, execute direto no prompt e veja se funciona, se funcionar depois basta adaptá-lo para um **.BAT**.   lembrando ainda que o comando está procurando por uma saída que tenha a palavra "pacotes", se a saída dos seus comandos aparecem em outro idioma você precisa substituir isso.

Comment: aeee agora funfou , vlw irmaozinho !

Comment: estou usando essa bat para tesar alguns links, to usando o errorlevel ta funcionado perfeitamente mas queria que quando eu nao tivesse comunicaçao ele ficasse de outra cor tipo vermelho .. se pingar fica verde a mensagem se nao pingar a mensagem fica vermelha ... sabe algo que possa me ajudar ?

Comment: Teria que entender como funciona essa comunicação pois não entendo nada desse **Ping**.  Se quero que o comando **2** aconteça somente se o comando **1**  foi executado com êxito, uso o **e-comercial** duplo (&&), tipo `calc.exe && notepad.exe`. Nesse caso o Bloco de Notas só abriria se a primeira ação (executar **calc.exe**) fosse executada com êxito. Também existe o **pipe** duplo (||), esse apenas executará o comando **2** se tiver ocorrido algum erro no comando **1**, por exemplo `calk.exe || calc.exe`.  Enfim, combine esses condicionais e você deve obter o resultado esperado, sorte aí. :)

Comment: ECHO.
ECHO TESTANDO COMUNICACAO COM A INTERNET , AGUARDE ...
ECHO.
ping -n 5 8.8.8.8 >>e:\LOG-AUTO-TESTE.txt
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
if %errorlevel% == 0 (
Echo
Echo            COMUNICACAO COM A INTERNET OK )
if %errorlevel% == 1 (
Echo
Echo ERRO AO SE COMUNICAR COM A INTERNET  )
echo.
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%i in ('ping -n 5 8.8.8.8^|find "ms"') do set "tempo=%%i"
echo.%tempo%
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%i in ('ping -n 5 8.8.8.8^|findstr /i "pacotes"') do set "tempo=%%i"
echo.%tempo%
echo.
echo.
echo.

Comment: esse e o comando ... testa ai , ai quando eu obter resposta quero verde , quando eu nao obter resposta quero vermelho .

Comment: usando o metodo que voce indicou ele muda as cores de tudo , e so desejo a cor do echo que avisa que nao obteve comunicação !